# Producing a new line with XSLT when transforming to HTML

Tags: html, xslt, newline

Transforming XML to HTML with XSLT, I need to introduce an actual newline character (**not a <br>**) into the HTML.

I can see how to do that when xsl:output method="text" - but not when method="html".

(I do realize the newline will have no effect on the browser-rendered content)

Any help appreciated.

Comment: The output method doesn't make any difference, if you know how to use e.g. `<xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>` or of course simply have literal result text nodes with newlines these end up in the HTML; the browser, unless inside of `pre` or with the necessary CSS will collapse white space to blanks but that is what you seem to know.

Comment: Where exactly is the problem? Please provide a [mcve].